# Tweepy Google App Engine Billing Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, tweepy

I am trying to post updates using tweepy and GAE.The code works fine in localhost.However when I upload it in GAE and try to open the URL I receive the following error:

```
raise TweepError('Failed to send request: %s' % e)
TweepError: Failed to send request: The Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been enabled in the admin console.
```

So my question is,does tweepy require billing to be enabled for use with app engine and
 is there any workaround to this?

The 3rd party libraries I have mentioned in app.yaml are webapp2 and ssl(tweepy requires it when using with app engine)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think tweepy needs billing per se, but tweepy seems to be hitting the Sockets API to do its job, and that API needs billing enabled.

You can enable billing and still stay under the free quota, just so you know, you just have to be wary of [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas). Mind you, you can always set a very low [daily budget](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#change_budget).

Comment: Thanks,but to activate billing I need a credit/debit card which I don't have.Is there any python wrapper around twitter API which does not use the Sockets API?

Comment: @SaikatDeshmukh Sorry for the delay in answering your comment. Unfortunately, I know of no such wrapper. Sorry